# WP Query with custom Shortcode

Tags: php, wp-query, query, search, meta-query

I have the following in my functions.php:-

```
/**
 * Shortcode: Latest Properties
 */

function latest_properties_func( $atts ) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> 5,
        'post_type'     => 'properties',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
    $latest_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$latest_properties = '';

      if( $latest_query->have_posts() ):

            while( $latest_query->have_posts() ) : $latest_query->the_post();

                $latest_price = get_field('house_price');

                $latest_properties .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
                $latest_properties .= '<div class="featured-wrapper">';
                $latest_properties .= '<div class="col-md-5">';
                $latest_properties .= get_the_post_thumbnail() . '<br />';
                $latest_properties .= '</div>';
                $latest_properties .= get_the_title() . '<br />';
                $latest_properties .= get_field('house_type') . '<br />';
                $latest_properties .= '£' . number_format($latest_price) . '<br />';
                $latest_properties .= '</div>';
                $latest_properties .= '</a>';
                $latest_properties .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';

            endwhile;

        endif; wp_reset_query();

 return $latest_properties;
}
add_shortcode( 'latest_properties', 'latest_properties_func' );
```

This shows the latest properties, and when I look at http://website.dev/properties/ it 5 of the latest properties as expected, however, when I visit http://website.dev/properties/?house_town=Leicester it only shows the latest properties where the house_town = Leicester.

I've realised that it is my search functionality that is causing this as shown below:-

```
// array of filters (field key => field name)
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
    'field_1'   => 'house_status',
    'field_2'   => 'house_type',
    'field_3'   => 'house_town',
    'field_4'   => 'house_price'
);

// action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) {

        return;

    }

    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    // loop over filters
    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {

        // continue if not found in url
        if( empty($_GET[ $name ]) ) {       
            continue;   
        }

        // get the value for this filter
        $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);

        // append meta query
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );

    } 

    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

}
```

My question is, how can I incorporate the two so they both work in conjunction with each other?

Answer (score 1):

There are few issue with your code

- When using `WP_Query` in conjuction with `the_post()` or using `get_posts()` in conjuction with `setup_postdata( $post )`, you need to reset the `$post` global with `wp_reset_postdata()`, not `wp_reset_query()`. `wp_reset_query()` is used in conjuction with `query_posts()` which you should never ever use
- You would want to reset posdata between your `endwhile` and `endif` statements. If you don't have any posts, there is no need to reset `$post` as you have never changed it.
- Where possible, you should avoid using globals. Globals are evil. WordPress has already made such a huge mess of it. Don't dirty global space any further. There are a couple of excellent posts on-site with extremely good alternatives to using globals. Be sure to make use of the on-site search function
- `pre_get_posts` alters all queries, front end and back end. You will specifically need to target a specific query on a specific page to avoid unexpected behavior. If you only need to target the main query on your search pahe, you will need to add the following conditions

  ```
  if (    !$query->is_main_query() // Bail if this is not the main query
       && !$query->is_search() // Bail if this is not the search page
  ) {
      return;
  }
  ```
- Never ever make use of unsanitized data coming from form inputs or from super globals. These are popular places which is used by hackers to inject malicious code into a website. **ALWAYS ALWAYS** sanitize, validate and/or escape any user supplied data according to the type of data you expect. Don't even trust your own input. A simple piece of code injected into a URL or a form field can give a hacker full access to your site which will compromise your complete site. If you are running a site with personal info, you can land yourself in jail for leaking personal info. So please, **ALWAYS SANITIZE, VALIDATE AND ESCAPE APPROPRIATELY**